# Finding the remainder of $11^{2013}$ divided by $61$

Tags: number-theory

How am I suppose to find the remainder when $11^{2013}$ is divided by $61$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT:

$11^2=121\equiv-1\pmod{61}$

So, $11^{2013}=11\cdot (11^2)^{1006}\equiv11\cdot(-1)^{1006}\pmod{61}$

$\implies 11^{2013}\equiv11\pmod{61}$

Comment: wow that was fast!  how do you know what you're suppose to do with questions like this?

Comment: @JongSui: The general answer to that question is exercising.

Comment: @JongSui, there are many ways.One shortcut is to find the smallest power of $11,$ which is $\equiv\pm1\pmod {61}$

Comment: @JongSui Your question is a very common exercise in introductory modular arithmetic. It's like saying that the general approach to minimizing one-variable functions is to differentiate.

Comment: Is it?  It appears to be very difficult to me maybe I'm just not a math person

Comment: Also look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersTotientTheorem.html, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy:
find the remainder of 11/61
                      11*11/61
                       11*11*11/61

11*11*11*11/61
until the remainder is 1. Once you found the power of 11 when the remainder is 1, you divide it by 2013. The remainder is the power of 11. The remainder of that is the answer!!!